# How to use std::make_shared<T> to a std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> without push_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, shared-ptr

So I have a class defined as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    T data;
};
```

Now I want to create a vector of shared pointers to A dynamically without push_back so that I can do it in parallel.

What I am doing for so is the following:

```
int k = 8;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A<int>>> myvec(k);
for(int i=0; i<k; ++i)
{
    myvec[i] = std::make_shared<A<int>>(new A<int>); // error here
}
```

Well, but I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'A<T>::A(const A<T> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1
from 'A<T> ' to 'const A<T> &'
```

How to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling what constructor twice? Did you look at the answer of that question? I don't see two constructor calls.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Okay! Thanks I got it.